# Web part vs add-in when integrating web application

Tags: web-part, sharepoint-addin, web-application, app

We are looking to integrate our web application (a capture component) into Sharepoint Online. The idea is that the user will be loading our app and have the ability to either open an item from a document library directly into it for editing (i.e. rearranging pdf pages) or scan a new document into our app and then directly save it into his Sharepoint doc library.

Our application client is loaded as a Javascript file (similar to Google Maps for example) and is rendered on an html-div. It doesn't require its own iframe or html body. It needs to be able to do CORS requests since it contains a server side component.

We are looking for advice on what is most appropriate for this, *web part* or *add-in*? *Hosted* or *Provider* add-in? It would be best if the user is able to add it in his site just like a Custom List for example.

We are not familiar with C# so avoiding writing aspx code is a plus but only if the same functionality can be otherwise achieved.

Answer (score 0):

Are you targeting on-line or on-prem? The really old answer would be server-side web parts (c#), which works on-prem and not online. This is no longer recommended, though you'll find folks still doing this who are working in environments where they aren't moving to the cloud. The old answer is add-in, where were introduced with SharePoint 2013. These work both on prem and in classic sites in the cloud. The new way is SPFx. SPFx works in the cloud as well as SharePoint 2016 with feature pack 2.